# Positioning nodes is inconsistent with tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, nodes, tikz-pic

Take a look at the following MWE

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx,tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=blue!10}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}

%################## Exercise 1 ###########################
\begin{frame} 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\node (x) at (0,.46) {$x$};
\node (y) at (0,0)   {$y$};
\node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y)+(1.5,.23)$)  (And) {};

\draw (x)  -- (And.input 1) ;
\draw (y)  -- (And.input 3) ;
\draw (And.output) -- node[above] {$xy$} ([xshift=1.5cm]And.output);
\node[above=of And] {AND};

%===============
\node (x1) at (5,.46) {$x$};
\node (y1) at (5,0)   {$y$};
\node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y1)+(1.5,.23)$)  (OR) {};

\draw (x1)  -- (OR.input 1) ;
\draw (y1)  -- (OR.input 3) ;
\draw (OR.output) -- node[above] {$x+y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]OR.output);
\node[above=of OR] {OR};


\node (x2) at (0,-2) {$x$};
\node[not gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x2)+(1.5,0)$)  (Not) {};

\draw (x2)  -- (Not.input) ;
\draw (Not.output) -- node[above] {$x'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Not.output);
\node[above=of Not] {Inverter};

\node (x3) at (5,-2) {$x$};
\node[buffer gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x3)+(1.5,0)$)  (Buffer) {};

\draw (x3)  -- (Buffer.input) ;
\draw (Buffer.output) -- node[above] {$x$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Buffer.output);
\node[above=of Buffer] {Buffer};


\node (x4) at (0,-3.56) {$x$};
\node (y4) at (0,-4)   {$y$};
\node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x4)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nand) {};

\draw (x4)  -- (Nand.input 1) ;
\draw (y4)  -- (Nand.input 3) ;
\draw (Nand.output) -- node[above] {$(xy)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nand.output);
\node[above=of Nand,,yshift=-.1cm] {NAND};


\node (x5) at (5,-3.56) {$x$};
\node (y5) at (5,-4)   {$y$};
\node[nor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x5)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nor) {};

\draw (x5)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
\draw (y5)  -- (Nor.input 3) ;
\draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$(x+y)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
\node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.1cm] {NOR};


\node (x6) at (0,-5.2) {$x$};
\node (y6) at (0,-5.43)   {$y$};
\node[xor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x6)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Xor) {};

\draw (x6)  -- (Xor.input 1) ;
\draw (y6)  -- (Xor.input 2) ;
\draw (Xor.output) -- node[above] {$xy'+ x'y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Xor.output);
\node[above=of Xor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XOR};



\node (x7) at (5,-5.2) {$x$};
\node (y7) at (5,-5.43)   {$y$};
\node[xnor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x7)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Nor) {};

\draw (x7)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
\draw (y7)  -- (Nor.input 2) ;
\draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$xy+ x'y'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
\node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XNOR};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

which yields this messy picture

[image]

In the standalone mode though, the output is satisfactory.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.2cm,label distance=2mm,very thick]

    \node (x) at (0,.46) {$x$};
    \node (y) at (0,0)   {$y$};
    \node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y)+(1.5,.23)$)  (And) {};

    \draw (x)  -- (And.input 1) ;
    \draw (y)  -- (And.input 3) ;
    \draw (And.output) -- node[above] {$xy$} ([xshift=1.5cm]And.output);
    \node[above=of And] {AND};

    %===============
    \node (x1) at (5,.46) {$x$};
    \node (y1) at (5,0)   {$y$};
    \node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y1)+(1.5,.23)$)  (OR) {};

    \draw (x1)  -- (OR.input 1) ;
    \draw (y1)  -- (OR.input 3) ;
    \draw (OR.output) -- node[above] {$x+y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]OR.output);
    \node[above=of OR] {OR};


    \node (x2) at (0,-2) {$x$};
    \node[not gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x2)+(1.5,0)$)  (Not) {};

    \draw (x2)  -- (Not.input) ;
    \draw (Not.output) -- node[above] {$x'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Not.output);
    \node[above=of Not] {Inverter};

    \node (x3) at (5,-2) {$x$};
    \node[buffer gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x3)+(1.5,0)$)  (Buffer) {};

    \draw (x3)  -- (Buffer.input) ;
    \draw (Buffer.output) -- node[above] {$x$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Buffer.output);
    \node[above=of Buffer] {Buffer};


    \node (x4) at (0,-3.56) {$x$};
    \node (y4) at (0,-4)   {$y$};
    \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x4)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nand) {};

    \draw (x4)  -- (Nand.input 1) ;
    \draw (y4)  -- (Nand.input 3) ;
    \draw (Nand.output) -- node[above] {$(xy)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nand.output);
    \node[above=of Nand,,yshift=-.1cm] {NAND};


    \node (x5) at (5,-3.56) {$x$};
    \node (y5) at (5,-4)   {$y$};
    \node[nor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x5)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nor) {};

    \draw (x5)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
    \draw (y5)  -- (Nor.input 3) ;
    \draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$(x+y)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
    \node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.1cm] {NOR};


    \node (x6) at (0,-5.2) {$x$};
    \node (y6) at (0,-5.43)   {$y$};
    \node[xor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x6)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Xor) {};

    \draw (x6)  -- (Xor.input 1) ;
    \draw (y6)  -- (Xor.input 2) ;
    \draw (Xor.output) -- node[above] {$xy'+ x'y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Xor.output);
    \node[above=of Xor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XOR};



    \node (x7) at (5,-5.2) {$x$};
    \node (y7) at (5,-5.43)   {$y$};
    \node[xnor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x7)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Nor) {};

    \draw (x7)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
    \draw (y7)  -- (Nor.input 2) ;
    \draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$xy+ x'y'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
    \node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XNOR};

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Any clues why this occurs? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Standalone has the same problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{siunitx,
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

%\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=blue!10}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}

%################## Exercise 1 ###########################
%\begin{frame} 
%\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\node (x) at (0,.46) {$x$};
\node (y) at (0,0)   {$y$};
\node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y)+(1.5,.23)$)  (And) {};

\draw (x)  -- (And.input 1) ;
\draw (y)  -- (And.input 3) ;
\draw (And.output) -- node[above] {$xy$} ([xshift=1.5cm]And.output);
\node[above=of And] {AND};

%===============
\node (x1) at (5,.46) {$x$};
\node (y1) at (5,0)   {$y$};
\node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y1)+(1.5,.23)$)  (OR) {};

\draw (x1)  -- (OR.input 1) ;
\draw (y1)  -- (OR.input 3) ;
\draw (OR.output) -- node[above] {$x+y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]OR.output);
\node[above=of OR] {OR};


\node (x2) at (0,-2) {$x$};
\node[not gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x2)+(1.5,0)$)  (Not) {};

\draw (x2)  -- (Not.input) ;
\draw (Not.output) -- node[above] {$x'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Not.output);
\node[above=of Not] {Inverter};

\node (x3) at (5,-2) {$x$};
\node[buffer gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x3)+(1.5,0)$)  (Buffer) {};

\draw (x3)  -- (Buffer.input) ;
\draw (Buffer.output) -- node[above] {$x$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Buffer.output);
\node[above=of Buffer] {Buffer};


\node (x4) at (0,-3.56) {$x$};
\node (y4) at (0,-4)   {$y$};
\node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x4)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nand) {};

\draw (x4)  -- (Nand.input 1) ;
\draw (y4)  -- (Nand.input 3) ;
\draw (Nand.output) -- node[above] {$(xy)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nand.output);
\node[above=of Nand,,yshift=-.1cm] {NAND};


\node (x5) at (5,-3.56) {$x$};
\node (y5) at (5,-4)   {$y$};
\node[nor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x5)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nor) {};

\draw (x5)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
\draw (y5)  -- (Nor.input 3) ;
\draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$(x+y)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
\node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.1cm] {NOR};


\node (x6) at (0,-5.2) {$x$};
\node (y6) at (0,-5.43)   {$y$};
\node[xor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x6)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Xor) {};

\draw (x6)  -- (Xor.input 1) ;
\draw (y6)  -- (Xor.input 2) ;
\draw (Xor.output) -- node[above] {$xy'+ x'y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Xor.output);
\node[above=of Xor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XOR};



\node (x7) at (5,-5.2) {$x$};
\node (y7) at (5,-5.43)   {$y$};
\node[xnor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x7)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Nor) {};

\draw (x7)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
\draw (y7)  -- (Nor.input 2) ;
\draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$xy+ x'y'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
\node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XNOR};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}

%\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Solution... Try to use automated distances wherever you can, so that you can solve these problems with two or three changes in the basic distances...

**After OPs edit: Beamer with the same code as tikzpicture works fine!**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{siunitx,
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

%\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=blue!10}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.2cm,label distance=2mm,very thick]

    \node (x) at (0,.46) {$x$};
    \node (y) at (0,0)   {$y$};
    \node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y)+(1.5,.23)$)  (And) {};

    \draw (x)  -- (And.input 1) ;
    \draw (y)  -- (And.input 3) ;
    \draw (And.output) -- node[above] {$xy$} ([xshift=1.5cm]And.output);
    \node[above=of And] {AND};

    %===============
    \node (x1) at (5,.46) {$x$};
    \node (y1) at (5,0)   {$y$};
    \node[or gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(y1)+(1.5,.23)$)  (OR) {};

    \draw (x1)  -- (OR.input 1) ;
    \draw (y1)  -- (OR.input 3) ;
    \draw (OR.output) -- node[above] {$x+y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]OR.output);
    \node[above=of OR] {OR};


    \node (x2) at (0,-2) {$x$};
    \node[not gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x2)+(1.5,0)$)  (Not) {};

    \draw (x2)  -- (Not.input) ;
    \draw (Not.output) -- node[above] {$x'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Not.output);
    \node[above=of Not] {Inverter};

    \node (x3) at (5,-2) {$x$};
    \node[buffer gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x3)+(1.5,0)$)  (Buffer) {};

    \draw (x3)  -- (Buffer.input) ;
    \draw (Buffer.output) -- node[above] {$x$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Buffer.output);
    \node[above=of Buffer] {Buffer};


    \node (x4) at (0,-3.56) {$x$};
    \node (y4) at (0,-4)   {$y$};
    \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x4)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nand) {};

    \draw (x4)  -- (Nand.input 1) ;
    \draw (y4)  -- (Nand.input 3) ;
    \draw (Nand.output) -- node[above] {$(xy)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nand.output);
    \node[above=of Nand,,yshift=-.1cm] {NAND};


    \node (x5) at (5,-3.56) {$x$};
    \node (y5) at (5,-4)   {$y$};
    \node[nor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nnn] at ($(x5)+(1.5,-.2)$)  (Nor) {};

    \draw (x5)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
    \draw (y5)  -- (Nor.input 3) ;
    \draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$(x+y)'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
    \node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.1cm] {NOR};


    \node (x6) at (0,-5.2) {$x$};
    \node (y6) at (0,-5.43)   {$y$};
    \node[xor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x6)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Xor) {};

    \draw (x6)  -- (Xor.input 1) ;
    \draw (y6)  -- (Xor.input 2) ;
    \draw (Xor.output) -- node[above] {$xy'+ x'y$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Xor.output);
    \node[above=of Xor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XOR};



    \node (x7) at (5,-5.2) {$x$};
    \node (y7) at (5,-5.43)   {$y$};
    \node[xnor gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(x7)+(1.5,-.12)$)  (Nor) {};

    \draw (x7)  -- (Nor.input 1) ;
    \draw (y7)  -- (Nor.input 2) ;
    \draw (Nor.output) -- node[above] {$xy+ x'y'$} ([xshift=1.5cm]Nor.output);
    \node[above=of Nor,,yshift=-.2cm] {XNOR};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I just didn't used `siunitx` but suppose it will not make difference

Comment: Nice research! (+1) But I believe that both you and the OP do not really use the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Take a look at my standalone code which yields acceptable output.

Comment: @marmot, I didn't used any syntax... Is an unchanged copy with removed the packages and commands that caused standalone not to work... It could not be done in a comment and made it an answer... The usefull think of the answer is my last sentence and that shows that the question is not really based on "true statements"...

Comment: I agree with all what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Careless mistake I've done. Basically in the beamer, the tikzpicture has this options

`\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]`

while in the standalone, it has these features

`\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.2cm,label distance=2mm,very thick]`

In the beamer,  tikzpicture should have same options which yields the correct output as the case in the standalone mode.